# Setting Environment variable in Visual studio C++project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I realize that similar questions were posted earlier but I need slightly different solution.
I have VS2012 C++ project A.vcxproj,that has debug1 configuration( platform x64) , and it builds corresponding .exe. It also uses a dll from other VS2012 C project B.vcxproj from a path that must be added to the environment variables. A.vcxproj.user file has following text

```
<LocalDebuggerEnvironment>PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\libsndfile\bin;..\..\lib\simulink\;$(LocalDebuggerEnvironment)  </LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
```

I need to add this setting automatically to the "A"project with following constraints

1. I cannot export user file as it as "per user", so cannot upload to our SCM system where other users can download it.
2. I tried adding code in main function, something like

   _putenv("PATH = ....\lib\simulink");
   but this does not work, as before the main file is compiled, it needs to search for the dll from specified path, which it dosn't .

Can anyone suggest a easy, portable fix , that i could distribute to all users through SCM, along with the project file.

I have also tried following:
--Created batch file setpath.bat with following content

```
@ECHO %PATH%  set PATH = %PATH%;C:\Program Files\libsndfile\bin;C:\dev\lib\simulink
```

-- added to A.vcxproj settings->build event->Pre-build->Command line

```
call  C:\setpath.bat
```

and I don't see the added paths under vS op window. neither does the VS User file gets the change, and running the project complains for missing dll error.
 --I tried to execute the batch file in
 A.vcxproj settings->
Custom build step->Execute before "Run"
 and still no result.

I guess the solution needs to add needed path to current environment variable for the time VS project is "run".

Thanks
sedy

Comment: If nobody can agree where this DLL needs to be stored then this cannot work of course.  Makes you wonder how this can ever come to a good end on the user's machine.  The trivial solution is to simply add the C project to the solution.  Now the DLL ends up where it belongs automatically.

Comment: @HansPassant These 2 projects need to be separate for various reasons, otherwise I would have done as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

added to A.vcxproj settings-> Build Events ->Pre-Build event

```
call setdllpath.bat
```

where the file contains the following:

```
@ECHO %PATH%
set COMSPEC = "%VCINSTALLDIR%\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
setx PATH "C:\Program Files\libsndfile\bin;..\..\lib\simulink" 
@ECHO %PATH%
```

So, once I build the Project, close Visual studio and open it again, and run the files wiithin project, it picks up dll correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Contents in `*.vcxproj.user`, `*.vcxproj.user` or `*.props` use the same xml schema so can be easily exchanged or included.

First if usefull you can add `UserMacros` to define the path to your libraries. 
Like bellow for the following two variable

```
PYTHONHOME=$(USERPROFILE)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
PYTHONPATH=$(PYTHONHOME)\DLLs;$(PYTHONHOME)\Lib;$(PYTHONHOME)\Lib\site-packages
```

Edit the `.vcxproj` adding inside `<Project>`:

```
  <Project .... >
  ...

  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros">
  <PYTHONHOME>$(USERPROFILE)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37</PYTHONHOME>
  <PYTHONPATH>$(PYTHONHOME)\DLLs;$(PYTHONHOME)\Lib;$(PYTHONHOME)\Lib\site-packages;</PYTHONPATH>      </PropertyGroup>

  ...
  </Project>
```

After you can add inside your build configuration, the following to set the `$(Path)` variable.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <LocalDebuggerEnvironment>Path=$(Path);$(PYTHONHOME);$(PYTHONHOME)\DLLs;$(PYTHONHOME)\Lib;$(PYTHONHOME)\Lib\site-packages;$(PYTHONHOME)\Scripts;$(PYTHONHOME);</LocalDebuggerEnvironment>
```